# Fractional part summation

Tags: number-theory, summation, fractional-part

Let us consider the sum  $$\displaystyle S_K=\sum_{n \geq \sqrt{K}}^{2 \sqrt{K}} \left\{ \sqrt {n^2-K} \right\}  $$ where $K$ is a positive integer and where $\{ \}$ indicates the fractional part. If we calculate the average value of the difference between $S_K$ and $1/2 \, \sqrt{K}$ over all positive integers $K \leq N$,  we have

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{K=1}^{N} \left( S_K- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{K} \right)= O(1)$$

for $N \rightarrow \infty \,\,$. I am interested in this $O(1)$ term, which seems to be different from zero. Accordingly, studying the behaviour of the difference $S_K -1/2 \, \sqrt{K}\,\,\,$ over all integer values of $K$, its distribution is slightly shifted with respect to zero, and the average value seems to be $\approx -0.32... \,\,$. I tried several approaches to determine this constant term, mostly based on the Euler-Maclaurin formula, but without success. I wonder what this term is, and how it comes into this distribution.

EDIT: These are two graphs to better illustrate the question. The first one is a plot of the difference between $S_K$ and $1/2 \, \sqrt{K}\,$ vs $K$, for the first $10^4$ values of $K$. The black line is the best fitting one and is set at a value of $\approx -0.32$.
[image]

The second graph is a plot of the average value of $S_K - 1/2 \, \sqrt{K}\,$, calculated over the first $N$ positive integers, vs $N$. As expected according to the first graph, the average value of the difference converges towards $\approx -0.32$.
[image]

Comment: Your chances for an answer would increase if people could understand what you're talking about. Do you mean the limit $S\infty$ as $K\to\infty$ of $$\displaystyle 
 S_K=\sum_{n \geq \sqrt{K}}^{2 \sqrt{K}} \left\{ \sqrt {n^2-K} \right\}  ?$$ Why do you think it exists? And if it does, the average of $|S_K-S_\infty|$ will converge to $0$, too.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I added some details to better clarify the question. I am interested in the distribution of the difference $ S_K - 1/2 \, \sqrt{K}$ over all  integer values of $K$. This difference seems to have an average value different from zero.

Comment: Why is the constant $2$ in $2\sqrt{K}$? Why not any $c > 1$ so the upper bound is $c\sqrt{K}$ or $(1+c)\sqrt{K}$ for $c > 0$?

Comment: Yes, I am primarily interested in the case of constant $2$ in the upper bound, but a generalization for any $c>1$ would be appreciated. Actually, the final constant term changes with $c$.

Comment: In your second displayed equation, on the LHS, $K$ is a summation variable running from $1$ to $N$. What, then, does $K$ mean on the RHS of the equation?

Comment: I have edited the equation to better clarify this issue.

Comment: With some handwaving, it seems the limit is $-\frac14\log(2+\sqrt{3}) \approx  -0.3292394742312041$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The definition of $S_K$ is complicated, it is hard to figure out a full asymptotic expansion for it.
Let us look at a simpler one which we do know.

For any integer $p > 0$, consider following sum:

$$F(p) = \sum_{k=1}^p \{ \sqrt{k} \}
= \sum_{k=1}^p \sqrt{k} - \sum_{k=1}^p \lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor\tag{*1}
$$

Let $x = \sqrt{p}$, $t = \{ x \}$ and $m = x - t = \lfloor x \rfloor$.

For the first term on RHS of $(*1)$, it has following asymptotic expansion:

$$\sum_{k=1}^p \sqrt{k} \asymp 
\frac23 x^3 + \frac12 x + \zeta\left(-\frac12\right) +
\frac{1}{24} x^{-1} -\frac{1}{1920} x^{-5} + \frac {1}{9216} x^{-9} +\cdots\tag{*2}
$$
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/445504/59379) for one way to derive this expansion.

For the second term, we can rewrite it as

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^p \lfloor \sqrt{k}\rfloor
&= \sum_{k=m^2}^p m + \sum_{\ell=1}^{m-1}\sum_{k=\ell^2}^{(\ell+1)^2-1}\ell\\
&= (p - m^2 + 1)m + \sum_{\ell=1}^{m-1} (2\ell+1)\ell
 = (p - m^2 + 1)m + \frac16 (m-1)m(4m+1)\\
&= (x-t)\left(x^2 - (x-t)^2 + 1 + \frac16(x-t-1)(4(x-t)+1)\right)
\end{align}\tag{*3}
$$
Substitute $(*2)$ and $(*3)$ into $(*1)$ and simplify, we obtain

$$F(p) = \frac12 p + A(t)\sqrt{p} + B(t) + \frac{1}{24} p^{-1/2} + \cdots\quad\text{where}\quad
\begin{cases}
A(t) = -(\frac13 + t - t^2)\\
B(t) = \zeta\left(-\frac12\right) + \frac56 t + \frac12 t - \frac13 t^3
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\displaystyle\;\int_0^1 A(t) dt = -\frac12 \ne 0$, even after
we subtract away the piece $-\frac12 p$, the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^p \left( \{ \sqrt{k} \} - \frac12 \right) = F(p) - \frac12 p$$

is still systematically biased by a term of the form $-\frac12 \sqrt{p}$. This is the source of the $O(1)$ term you notice.
To see this, let us rewrite the sum at hand in terms of $F(p)$.

Let $\theta_K = \#\{ n \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} : \sqrt{K} \le n \le 2\sqrt{K} \}$,
the sum at hand can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{K=1}^N \left( S_K - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{K} \right)
= \underbrace{\sum_{K=1}^N \sum_{\sqrt{K} \le n \le 2\sqrt{K}}\left(\left\{ \sqrt{n^2 - K} \right\} - \frac12\right)}_{\mathcal{I}}
- \underbrace{\frac12 \sum_{K=1}^N \left(\sqrt{K} - \theta_K\right)}_{\mathcal{J}}
$$
For the first term $\mathcal{I}$, we can express it using at most two $F(\cdot)$.
$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \sum_{n=1}^{2\sqrt{N}}\sum_{\frac14 n^2 \le K \le \min( N, n^2 )}
\left(\left\{ \sqrt{n^2 - K} \right\} - \frac12\right)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{2\sqrt{N}}\sum_{ \max(0,n^2 - N)\le \ell \le \frac34 n^2}
\left(\left\{ \sqrt{\ell} \right\} - \frac12\right)\\
&= -\frac12\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor + \sum_{n=1}^{2\sqrt{N}}\sum_{ \max(1,n^2 - N)\le \ell \le \frac34 n^2}
\left(\left\{ \sqrt{\ell} \right\} - \frac12\right) \\
&= -\frac12\lfloor\sqrt{N}\rfloor + \sum_{n=1}^{2\sqrt{N}}\left[ F(p) - \frac12 p \right]_{p = \max(0,n^2-N-1)}^{\lfloor \frac34 n^2\rfloor}
\end{align}
$$
For the second term $\mathcal{J}$, one can show
$$\sum_{K=1}^p \theta_K = \sum_{K=1}^p \left(\lfloor\sqrt{K}\rfloor + \frac12\right) + \frac12 | p - m(m+1) |$$
This implies $\mathcal{J}$ falls of like $\sqrt{N}$ and one can ignore them 
in the final limit
$$\mathcal{J} = \frac12\sum_{K=1}^N \left(\sqrt{K} - \theta_K \right)
= \frac12( A(t) - \frac12|1-2t|)\sqrt{N} + O(1)\quad\text{ where }\quad t = \{\sqrt{N}\}$$

To proceed further, we will wave our hands. We will assume

1. only the leading term $A(t)\sqrt{p}$ in $F(p) - \frac12 p$ matters.
2. we can average out $A(t)$ over $t$, i.e. replace $A(t)\sqrt{p}$ by $-\frac12\sqrt{p}$
3. we can approximate the sum over $n$ by an integral over $n$

Changing variable to $n = \sqrt{N}s$, we find

$$\begin{align}\frac1N\sum_{K=1}^N \left( S_K- \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{K} \right)
= \frac{\mathcal{I}}{N} + O (N^{-1/2})
&\approx 
-\frac{1}{2N} \left[
\int_0^{2\sqrt{N}} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} n dn
- \int_{\sqrt{N}}^{2\sqrt{N}}\sqrt{n^2-N} dn\right]\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}
\left[ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \int_0^{2}  s ds 
- \int_1^2 \sqrt{s^2 - 1}ds \right]\\
&= -\frac14\log(2+\sqrt{3}) \approx -0.3292394742312041
\end{align}
$$
A number compatible with what OP described in question.

Comment: This is a nice answer, thank you. I will wait to accept it only to see whether someone else has different approaches to propose.

Comment: Thank you again for your nice solution. Could your answer be generalized to the case in which $S_k$ has an upper bound equal to $c \sqrt{K}$? If so, should the result be $1/4 \log(c+\sqrt{c^2-1})$? And similarly, could your method be used with an upper bound of higher degree, for example $cK$?

Comment: @Anatoly I think it is possible to generalize to $c\sqrt{K}$ but it will take sometime for me to remember what I has done and go over the algebra again. Maybe later over the weekend, but keep your fingers crossed ;-p

Comment: @Anatoly The contribution from first term $\mathcal{I}$ is essentially the same. Under same approximation, it gives $\color{red}{-}\frac14 \log(c+\sqrt{c^2-1})$. I  cannot work out the correct form of second term $\mathcal{J}$ yet but I think its contribution remains to be $O(N^{-1/2})$ and hence ignorable.

Comment: Thank you again for your further comment. As regards the case where the upper bound is of higher  degree I have just posted a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2443783/fractional-part-summation-and-asymptotic-expansion-error