# On the asymptotics of $\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \{\sqrt{k}\} $

Tags: summation, asymptotics, radicals, fractional-part

On the asymptotics of
$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \{\sqrt{k}\}
$

This was inspired
by a problem in Quora
which asked to show that
$s(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \{\sqrt{k}\}
\le \frac{n^2-1}{2}
$.

($\{...\}$ means
fractional part.)

Getting bounds on
$s(n)$
is relatively straightforward:

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \{\sqrt{k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j^2}^{j^2+2j} \{\sqrt{k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \{\sqrt{j^2+k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} (\sqrt{j^2+k}-j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} (\sqrt{j^2+k}-j)\dfrac{\sqrt{j^2+k}+j}{\sqrt{j^2+k}+j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{j^2+k}+j}\\
&\le\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \dfrac{k}{2j}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{2j}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} k\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{2j}\dfrac{2j(2j+1)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac12\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}(2j+1)\\
&=\dfrac{n^2-1}{2}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \dfrac{k}{\sqrt{j^2+k}+j}\\
&\gt\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \dfrac{k}{2j+1}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{2j+1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} k\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{2j+1}\dfrac{2j(2j+1)}{2}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\\
&=\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
\end{array}
$

The obvious next step
is to get
more precise bounds on $s(n)$.

I can show that
$s(n)
-(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{3})
$
is bounded
by writing

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} (\sqrt{j^2+k}-j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\sum_{k=0}^{2j} (\sqrt{1+k/j^2}-1)\\
\end{array}
$

and using
$1+x/2-x^2/8+x^3/16
\ge \sqrt{1+x}
\ge 1+x/2-x^2/8
$.

(It turns out that
using the upper bound
$1+x/2
\ge \sqrt{1+x}
$
is not enough,
because a $\ln(n)$
term appears.)

The result I get is

$-(\frac1{6}
+\frac{1}{24}\zeta(2)+\frac1{4}\zeta(3)+\frac{5}{48}\zeta(4))
\approx -0.648 \\
\le s(n)
-(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{3})\\
\le -\frac1{6}+\frac{5}{24}\zeta(2)+\frac1{16}\zeta(3)
\approx 0.2511.
$

Computation shows that
the limit is about
$-.2074
$.

So,
my questions are:

Does the limit
$\lim_{n \to \infty}
s(n)
-(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{3})
$
exist?

If so,
what is it?

I am sure that the limit exists,
but I do not know 
what it might be.

Comment: Actually you can get the exact expression of $e(n) \triangleq \sum_{k=0}^n \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor $ by using the same cutting you made in your proof. So having $s(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt(k} - e(n)$ you can also approximate $\sum_{k=0}^n \sqrt(k}$

Comment: It holds that $$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{n^2 } {\left\{ {\sqrt k } \right\}}  \sim \frac{{n^2 }}{2} - \frac{n}{3} + \zeta \left( { - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) + \frac{1}{{24n}} -\frac{1}{1920n^5}+  \cdots \, .
$$ See the accepted answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404754/fractional-part-summation

Comment: That $\zeta(-1/2)$ agrees with my computations.

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying to realize
that taking a different path,
as suggested in the comments,
would have provided
a direct solution.

I make use of
the result 
of Marko Riedel
linked to by EDX and Gary that
$\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}
\sim
\frac23 n^{3/2}+\frac12\sqrt {n}
+\zeta  \left( -\frac12 \right) +
{\frac {1}{24\sqrt {n}}}
-{\frac {1}{1920{n}^{5/2}}}\,+{\frac {1}{9216{n}^{9/2}}} +\cdots
$.

This implies that

$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2}\sqrt{k}
\sim
\frac23 n^3+\frac{n}{2}
+\zeta  \left( -\frac12 \right) +
{\frac {1}{24n}}
-{\frac {1}{1920n^5}}+\frac {1}{9216n^9} +\cdots
$

so that

$\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1}\sqrt{k}
\sim
\frac23 n^3-\frac{n}{2}
+\zeta  \left( -\frac12 \right) +
{\frac {1}{24n}}
-{\frac {1}{1920n^5}}+\frac {1}{9216n^9} +\cdots
$

I find it amusing that
this result was in response
to a question of mine.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n)
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2} \{\sqrt{k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j^2}^{j^2+2j} \{\sqrt{k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \{\sqrt{j^2+k}\}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} (\sqrt{j^2+k}-j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \sqrt{j^2+k}-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} j\\
&=s_1(n)-s_2(n)\\
s_1(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} \sqrt{j^2+k}\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=j^2}^{(j+1)^2-1} \sqrt{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n^2-1} \sqrt{k}\\
&=\dfrac23 n^3-\dfrac{n}{2}
+\zeta  \left( -\dfrac12 \right) +
{\dfrac {1}{24n}}
-{\dfrac {1}{1920n^5}}+\dfrac {1}{9216n^9} +\cdots\\
s_2(n)
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{2j} j\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j(2j+1)\\
&=2\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j^2+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}j\\
&=2\dfrac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3-3n^2+n}{3}+\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{4n^3-6n^2+2n+3n^2-3n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{4n^3-3n^2-n}{6}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3}{3}-\dfrac{n^2}{2}-\dfrac{n}{6}\\
\text{so}\\
s(n)
&=s_1(n)-s_2(n)\\
&=\dfrac{n^2}{2}-\dfrac{n}{3}
+\zeta  \left( -\dfrac12 \right) +
{\dfrac {1}{24n}}
-{\dfrac {1}{1920n^5}}+\dfrac {1}{9216n^9} +\cdots\\
\end{array}
$

This agrees with
Gary's comment.