# Summation of square root fractional part

Tags: number-theory, summation, fractional-part

Is there a way to calculate the following sum for large $c>K$, closed-form or approximation?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{c}\left\{\sqrt{K+n^2}\right\}$$Where K and n are positive integers and $\{\}$ indicates the fractional part.

A similar question: [Fractional part summation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404754/fractional-part-summation)

Comment: Hint: when $n$ is large compared to $\sqrt K$ then $\sqrt{K+n^2}-n \sim \frac{K}{2n}$.

Comment: @RuanSunkel are you satisfied with my answer?

Comment: Hi @fwd, I am still busy digesting. So far I am happy with the answer, I learned a lot. Looking at the question and the answer, I think what I am really interested in is the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term in $\sum_2$, calculating it given a specific $K$ and $c$, so basically calculating the actual value of $\sum_2$. Thinking of maybe asking a follow up question.

Answer (score 2):

The given sum can be written as
$$
\Sigma = \Sigma_1 - \Sigma_2
$$
where
$$
\Sigma_1 = \sum_{n=1}^{c} \sqrt{n^2 + K}
$$
and
$$
\Sigma_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{c} \lfloor\sqrt{n^2 + K}\rfloor.
$$
Now using $H_n = \log n + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(1/n)$ where $H_n$ is the $n$-th harmonic number,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{c} \sqrt{n^2 + K} - n &= \sum_{n=1}^c \frac{K}{\sqrt{n^2 + K} + n} \\
                                  &\le \frac{K}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{c} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{K}{2}(\log c + \gamma + \mathcal{O}(1/c)).
\end{align*}
Hence
$$
\Sigma_{1} = \sum_{n=1}^{c} \sqrt{n^2 + K} = \frac{1}{2}c(c+1) + \frac{K}{2}(\log c + \gamma) + \mathcal{O}(1/c)
$$

Let $A = \lfloor\sqrt{K+1} - 1\rfloor$. Then,
\begin{align*}
  \Sigma_{2} = \sum_{n=1}^{c} \lfloor\sqrt{n^2 + K}\rfloor &= \sum_{j=1}^{A}\sum_{\frac{K-(j+1)^2}{2(j+1)} < n \le \frac{K-j^2}{2j}}(n+j) + \sum_{\frac{K-1}{2} < n \le c}n \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^c n +  \sum_{j=1}^{A}\sum_{\frac{K-(j+1)^2}{2(j+1)} < n \le \frac{K-j^2}{2j}}j\\
&= \frac{1}{2}c(c+1) + \sum_{j=1}^A j\left(\frac{3}{2} + \frac{K}{2j(j+1)}+ \mathcal{O}(1)\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}c(c+1) + \frac{3}{4}A(A+1) + \frac{K}{2}(H_A - 1) + \mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{j=1}^A j\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2}c(c+1) + \frac{3}{4}A(A+1) + \frac{K}{2}(H_A - 1) + \mathcal{O}(1)
\end{align*}
since $\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{j=1}^A j\right) = \mathcal{O}(K) = \mathcal{O}(1)$.

Thus,

\begin{align*}
\Sigma &= \frac{K}{2}(\log c + \gamma) - \frac{3}{4}A(A+1) - \frac{K}{2}(H_A - 1) + \mathcal{O}(1).\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I did a quick test and $\sum_2$ seems to be different than expected. For example, with $K=15$, and $c=16$, $\sum_2=146$, but $\sum_2$ provided in the answer gives $\sum_2=2822$. Please correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: you're right, something's wrong

Comment: @RuanSunkel I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you @fwd. Can you please elaborate on the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ constant that depends on $K$?

Comment: @RuanSunkel I added more details to show where the $\mathcal{O}(1)$ term comes from. The larger $K$ is, the larger this term is. Numerical plots suggest that it grows linearly in $K$. But since $K$ is fixed, it's just  $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: How was the sum for ${\Sigma}_{2}$ derived?