# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(4\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(-1)^i\sqrt{i}\right)-\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{2n+1}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

Ratio test gives me $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{2(n+1)}-3\sqrt{1+2(n+1)}+3\sqrt{2+2(n+1)}-\sqrt{3+2(n+1)}}{\sqrt{2n}-3\sqrt{1+2n}+3\sqrt{2+2n}-\sqrt{3+2n}}=1$, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Mathematica gives

```
-Sqrt[2] Sqrt[n]-Sqrt[1+2 n]+
4 ((-1+2 Sqrt[2]) Zeta[-(1/2)]+
(-1)^(2 n) Sqrt[2] Zeta[-(1/2),1/2+n,IncludeSingularTerm->False]
+(-1)^(1+2 n) Sqrt[2] Zeta[-(1/2),1+n,IncludeSingularTerm->False])
```

And is numerically converging to $-1.52041\ldots$.

Comment: The sum converges to $4(\sqrt{8}-1)\zeta(-\frac12) \approx -1.520419250438736...$
You can derive this yourself using an asymptotic expansion from this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/445504/59379):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/2} \asymp \frac23 n^{3/2} + \frac12 n^{1/2} + \zeta(-1/2) + \cdots$$

Comment: @achillehui How to deal with the alternating term?

Comment: @gimusi $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\sqrt{k} = 2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sqrt{2k} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\sqrt{k}$ i.e. even - odd = 2even - (even+odd).

Comment: @achillehui Thanks, nice trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n = 4\sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^k \sqrt{k} - \sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{2n+1}$ be the finite sum at hand. We are going to show

1. $S_\infty \stackrel{def}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ exists.
2. $S_\infty = 4(\sqrt{8}-1)\zeta(-\frac12) \approx -1.520419250438736...$

Unlike its exact value, the existence of $S_\infty$ can be justified using elementary methods.
Let $a_k$ be the coefficient of $\sqrt{k}$ in above expression of $S_n$. Notice

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} a_k t^k 
&= 4\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k t^k - t^{2n}(1+t)
= -4t\frac{1-t^{2n}}{1+t} + (1-t^{2n})(1+t) -(1+t)\\
&= -1-t + ((1+t)^2 - 4t)\frac{1-t^{2n}}{1+t}
= -1-t + (1-2t+t^2)\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1} t^{k-1}\end{align}$$
We can rewrite $S_n$ to have the form of an alternating sum:
$$S_n = -1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k}b_k\quad\text{ where }\quad b_k = 2\sqrt{k} - \sqrt{k-1} - \sqrt{k+1}$$

Notice as $k$ increases,
$$\begin{align}b_k 
&= (\sqrt{k}-\sqrt{k-1}) - (\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}
= \frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k-1}}{(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})}\\
&= \frac{2}{(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k}+\sqrt{k-1})(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})}
\end{align}
$$
monotonically decreases to zero. By [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), $-1 + \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k b_k$ is a converging series. 
Since $S_n$ is a sub-sequence of its partial sums, $S_n$ converges.

To evaluate $S_\infty$, let $T_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^k\sqrt{k}$. We have
$S_n = 4T_n - \sqrt{2n} - \sqrt{2n+1}$ and
$$T_n = \left(\sum_{k=1,\text{even}}^{2n} - \sum_{k=1,\text{odd}}^{2n}\right)\sqrt{k} = \left(2\sum_{k=1,\text{even}}^{2n} - \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\right)\sqrt{k}
= \sqrt{8}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{2n}\sqrt{k}
$$
It is known that the sum over $\sqrt{k}$ has following asymptotic expansion (e.g. see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/445504/59379))
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1/2} \asymp \frac23 n^{3/2} + \frac12 n^{1/2} + K + \frac{1}{24}n^{-1/2} + \cdots\quad\text{ where } K = \zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$$

Substitute this expansion into expression of $T_n$, we find
$$\begin{align}
S_n
&= 4\sqrt{8}\left(\frac23 n^{3/2} + \frac12 n^{1/2} + K\right)
 - 4\left(\frac23 (2n)^{3/2} + \frac12 (2n)^{1/2} + K\right)
- 2\sqrt{2n} + O(n^{-1/2})\\
&= 4(\sqrt{8}-1)K + O(n^{-1/2})
\end{align}
$$
As a result,
$S_\infty = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} S_n = 4(\sqrt{8}-1)\zeta\left(-\frac12\right) \approx
-1.520419250438736...$

Answer (score 0):

I will show that
the limit exists.

If
$s_n
=\left(4\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(-1)^i\sqrt{i}\right)-\sqrt{2n}-\sqrt{2n+1}
$
then,
using
$\sqrt{1+x}
=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^2}{8} + O(x^3)
$
with the constant in 
the big-oh satisfying
$0 < c < \frac1{16}$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}-s_n
&=4(\sqrt{2n+2}-\sqrt{2n+1})-(\sqrt{2n+2}+\sqrt{2n+3})+(\sqrt{2n}+\sqrt{2n+1})\\
&=3\sqrt{2n+2}-3\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n+3}+\sqrt{2n}\\
&=\sqrt{2n}(3\sqrt{1+1/n}-3\sqrt{1+1/(2n)})-\sqrt{1+3/(2n)}+1)\\
&=\sqrt{2n}(3(1+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{8n^2} + O(\frac1{n^3}))
-3(1+\frac{1}{4n}-\frac{1}{32n^2} + O(\frac1{n^3}))
-(1+\frac{3}{4n}-\frac{9}{32n^2} + O(\frac1{n^3}))+1)\\
&=\sqrt{2n}(\frac{1}{n}(\frac32 -\frac34-\frac34)
-\frac{1}{n^2}(-\frac38+\frac{3}{32}+\frac{9}{32})+ O(\frac1{n^3})))\\
&=O(\frac1{n^{5/2}})\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of this converges
(because of the
bounded coefficients 
of the
$O(\frac1{n^3})$
terms).