# Euler-Maclaurin Summation

Tags: summation, asymptotics, euler-maclaurin

Using EM summation formula estimate 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k
$$

up to the term involving $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}$

My attempt is 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k  = \frac{2 \sqrt{n^3}}{3} -\frac{2}{3}  + \frac 1 2 (\sqrt n -1)+ \frac{1}{24} (\frac{1}{\sqrt n} -1) + \int_1^n P_{2k+1}(x)f^{(2k+1)}(x)dx
$$
I am not sure what can be said about the integral. Please tell me if I have made a mistake and how I can solve the integral? Have I stopped the summation at the right point?

Comment: This was also discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442470), which you may find enlightening.

Answer (score 8):

Using the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, we get
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}=\tfrac23n^{3/2}+\tfrac12n^{1/2}+\zeta(-\tfrac12)+\tfrac1{24}n^{-1/2}-\tfrac1{1920}n^{-5/2}+\tfrac1{9216}n^{-9/2}+O(n^{-13/2})
$$
where the constant $\zeta(-\frac12)=-0.20788622497735456602$ is explained below.

---

By the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, we have for $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt-1$
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-s}=\frac1{1-s}n^{1-s}+\frac12n^{-s}+\zeta_\ast(s)+O(n^{-s-1})\tag{1}
$$
Define the sequence of functions
$$
\zeta_n(s)=\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-s}-\frac1{1-s}n^{1-s}-\frac12n^{-s}\tag{2}
$$
For all $n\ge1$, $\zeta_n(s)$ is analytic. For $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\zeta_n(s)=\zeta(s)$. Estimate $(1)$ says that on compact subsets of $\{s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}:\mathrm{Re(s)\gt-1}\}$, $\zeta_n(s)$ converges uniformly. Thus, for $s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{1\}$ and $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt-1$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\zeta_n(s)$ is analytic, so by analytic continuation, for $\mathrm{Re}(s)\gt-1$,
$$
\zeta_\ast(s)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\zeta_n(s)=\zeta(s)\tag{3}
$$

Comment: @Robjon There were typos in the first non-enumerated equation ($x$ instead of $n$).  I took the liberty of editing.  I hope that you don't mind.  I also edited my answer and would like to hear your thoughts on this expansion to $x^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Hi Rob.  I hope that all is well.  Just to clarify … Are you applying the AC to the punctured plane since $\zeta(s)$ is meromorphic with a single simple pole at $s=1$?

Comment: @MarkViola: yes. I guess I should have said "compact subsets of $\{s\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}:\mathrm{Re(s)\gt-1}\}$". I have updated the post.   I missed that point because I was mainly interested in the leftward extension made possible by the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula.

Comment: You mean $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{1\}$, I believe.

Comment: (+1) for the very well-written solution!

Answer (score 5):

The correct expansion is given by

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n f(i) &= \int_1^n f(x)dx + B_1 [f(n)+f(1)]\\\\
& + \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} \left(f^{(2k-1)}(n)-f^{(2k-1)}(1)\right)\\\\
& +\frac{1}{(2m+1)!}\int_1^n P_{2m+1}(x)f^{(2m+1)}(x)
\end{align}$$

For $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ and $m=1$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{i}&=\frac23 (n^{3/2}-1)+\frac12 (n^{1/2}+1)+\frac{1}{24}(n^{-1/2}-1)+\frac{1}{3!}\int_1^n P_3(x)f^{(3)}(x)dx\\\\
&=\frac23x^{3/2}+\frac12n^{1/2}+\left(-\frac23+\frac12-\frac{1}{24}\right)+\frac{1}{24}n^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{3!}\int_1^n P_3(x)f^{(3)}(x)dx
\end{align}$$

The next task is to determine an estimate for the remainder $R$ where $R$ is the integral

$$R\equiv \frac{1}{3!}\int_1^n P_3(x)f^{(3)}(x)dx$$

---

We can find an estimate for the integral term

$$\int_1^n P_{3}(x)f^{(3)}(x)dx \tag1$$

using the well-known expression for the [Bernoulli Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)

$$B_3(x)=x^3-\frac32 x^2+\frac12 x$$

We can easily verify that

$$-\frac{1}{12\sqrt{3}}<B_3(x)<\frac{1}{12\sqrt{3}}$$

for $x\in [0,1]$.  Since $P_{2k+1}(x)=B_{2k+1}(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$ then we see immediately that for $1<x<n$

$$-\frac{1}{12\sqrt{3}}< P_{3}(x) < \frac{1}{12\sqrt{3}}\tag 2$$

Now, we note that for $f(x)=x^{1/2}$, $f^{3}(x)=\frac38 x^{-5/2}>0$ for $x\in [1,n]$.  Now, we use $(2)$ in the estimate of $(1)$ to reveal

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{48\sqrt{3}}\left(1-n^{-3/2}\right)<\int_1^n P_{3}(x)f^{(3)}(x)dx \le \frac{1}{48\sqrt{3}}\left(1-n^{-3/2}\right)
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have the upper and lower bounds

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}\le \frac23n^{3/2}+\frac12n^{1/2}+\left(-\frac{5}{24}+\frac{1}{288\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{24}n^{-1/2}-\frac{1}{288\sqrt{3}}n^{-3/2}}$$
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}\ge \frac23n^{3/2}+\frac12n^{1/2}+\left(-\frac{5}{24}-\frac{1}{288\sqrt{3}}\right)+\frac{1}{24}n^{-1/2}+\frac{1}{288\sqrt{3}}n^{-3/2}}$$

Comment: The difference of the upper and lower bounds is $\frac1{144\sqrt3}$ which is bigger than $\frac1{24}n^{-1/2}$ for $n\gt108$. However, computing the actual values, both formulas on the right are over-estimates for the sum.

Comment: @robjohn Well, I found the error.  I added $-2/3 +1/2-1/24$ and incorrectly got $-1/8$ (this is the reason to forgo doing arithmetic in my head late at night) edited version.  The sum is actually $-5/24\approx. 0.20833$.  The bounds are now correct.  I do really want to thank you for all of the comments!

Comment: Now the bounds do bracket the sum. (+1) However for $n\gt108$, the difference in the bounds makes the last two terms insignificant.  One point of the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula is that there is a constant that can replace $\left(-\frac5{24}+\frac1{288\sqrt3}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac5{24}-\frac1{288\sqrt3}\right)$. Even if it can't be determined symbolically, it can be evaluated numerically. Using the terms in my answer, and $n=1000$, we can compute $23$ places of the constant, since the next term is $-\frac{11}{163840}n^{-13/2}$.

Comment: @robjohn Yes, I understand that your approach is the better way.  It is really pretty cool!  But, rather than duplicate, I wanted to provide the OP with a more "brute force" way forward.

Comment: Yes, you are doing things using the integration by parts development. There is nothing wrong with that and it does give concrete bounds. Although I was concentrating on its numerical limitations, I didn't mean to deprecate your work (I did upvote :-). I simply wanted to point out that, in most cases, it is possible to compute the constant fairly accurately.

Comment: @robjohn I took your comments as positive feedback - never thought you were depreciating my work.  And you are absolutely correct about its numerical limitations.   I posted and deleted a second answer in which I expanded to $O(n^{-11/2})$ and unless I made a careless error, the upper and lower bounds for $\zeta(-1/2)$ become more crude.

Comment: Since the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula only uses odd derivatives, the $O(n^{-11/2})$ term, being the sixth derivative, should be $0$. Once we compute $\frac1{9216}n^{-9/2}$, the next term should be $O(n^{-13/2})$. I don't know if that has anything to do with the unfortunate estimate for $\zeta(-\frac12)$.

Comment: @robjohn While it is true that if we continue with the series, there is no term of order $n^{-11/2}$, the remainder term is proportional to $\int_1^n P_7(x)f^{(7)}(x)dx$ and the integral of $f^{(7)}$ is indeed $f^{(6)}(x) \sim x^{-11/2}$.  I suspect the issue is the gross overestimate of the integral from using the maximum (minimum) of a pseudo-oscillatory function $P_7(x)$ to estimate $P_7(x)$ throughout the entire domain of integration.  While it provided a reasonable approximation for the expansion through $n^{-3/2}$, it fails in the refined expansion.