# How to estimate $ \left(1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \dots + \sqrt{n} \right) - \frac{2}{3} n \sqrt{n}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

How do I estimate the error for the sum of reciprocals of square roots.  From calculus we know that:

$$ \int_0^n \sqrt{x} \, dx  = \frac{2}{3} x\sqrt{x} \;\;\Bigg|_{x=0}^{x=n} = \frac{2}{3}n\sqrt{n}$$

I forget the name - [midpoint rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method), [trapezoid rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule) ?? - basically we want to approximate the integral as a Riemann sum.  How do we estimate the error?

$$ \left(1 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \dots +  \sqrt{n} \right)  - \frac{2}{3} n \sqrt{n}$$

To give you a sense of how much we are losing on this approximation, let's   draw two pictures.

[image]
[image]

We are losing all the gray stuff in our approximation, which is quite a lot!  I don't really care about the integral, what's important is the difference between all the stuff we are adding and square root of $n$.

The yellow triangle has base $1$ and height $\sqrt{14} - \sqrt{13}$ so the area is:

$$ A = \frac{1}{2} \times b \times h = \frac{1}{2} \times 1 \times (\sqrt{\color{#E0E070}{14}} - \sqrt{\color{#E0E070}{13}}) = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n}) \approx \frac{1}{4 \sqrt{n}}$$

This suggests the total of all errors is about $\propto \sqrt{\color{#D22}{n}}$ which is not a small amount.  Can anyone get the constant of proportionality?

The [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) machine does crank out such error estimates, but the [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) function is not so strange. **Can we derive such an estimate in this specific case using basic standard inequalities?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A trapezoidal rule gives a much better approximation: $$\sum_1^n i^{1/2}\approx \frac 1 2(f(1)+f(n))+\int_1^n f(x)\,dx= \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 2 \sqrt n +\frac 2 3 n^{3/2}-\frac 2 3$$ which recovers the biggest component of the error and ends up with an error bound by a small constant.
[Error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis) can also improve the above estimate to
$$\sum_1^n i^{1/2}=\frac 2 3n^{3/2}+\frac 1 2n^{1/2}-\frac 1 6-\frac 1 {24}+\frac 1{24}n^{-1/2}+E_n$$
where non-negative $E_n$ is tiny ($<5\cdot 10^{-4}$).

Comment: Indeed, if we add up the area of the $\color{#20E070}{\text{green}} $ rectangle and the $\color{#E0E070}{\text{yellow}}$ triangle, we do get a [trapezium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid), whose area is $A = \frac{1}{2} \times b \times (h_1 + h_2)$.

Comment: @cactus Simple [error analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis) also shows that simply subtracting $\frac 1 {12}f'(1)=\frac 1{24}$ from the above estimate will recover most of the constant error term (error of less than $4.5\cdot 10^{-4}$ from the correct constant).

Comment: my question was originally about $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ but I simplified it to $\sum \sqrt{n}$ after I drew the wrong charts :-P for me the surprise is how accurate I can get my answer without using any calculus at all.  there are many result of this kind where I could try to use the same principle.  Thank you.

Comment: @cactus Can't avoid calculus if you integrate to approximate a sum ;).

Comment: I am also pointing out a typo in your response... you say $\sum i^{\color{red}{-}1/2}$ you should take out the minus sign.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Binomial Theorem, we get
$$
\begin{align}
k^{3/2}-(k-1)^{3/2}
&=k^{3/2}\left[1-\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{3/2}\right]\\
&=k^{3/2}\left[\frac3{2k}-\frac3{8k^2}-\frac1{16k^3}+O\left(\frac1{k^4}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac32k^{1/2}-\frac38k^{-1/2}-\frac1{16}k^{-3/2}+O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
k^{1/2}-(k-1)^{1/2}
&=k^{1/2}\left[1-\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{1/2}\right]\\
&=k^{1/2}\left[\frac1{2k}+\frac1{8k^2}+O\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)\right]\\
&=\frac12k^{-1/2}+\frac18k^{-3/2}+O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
k^{-1/2}-(k-1)^{-1/2}
&=k^{-1/2}\left[1-\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{-1/2}\right]\\
&=k^{-1/2}\left[-\frac1{2k}+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)\right]\\
&=-\frac12k^{-3/2}+O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Combining $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
&\small\left(\frac23k^{3/2}+\frac12k^{1/2}+\frac1{24}k^{-1/2}\right)-\left(\frac23(k-1)^{3/2}+\frac12(k-1)^{1/2}+\frac1{24}(k-1)^{-1/2}\right)\\[6pt]
&\small=k^{1/2}+O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Summing, we get that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/2}=\frac23n^{3/2}+\frac12n^{1/2}+C+\frac1{24}n^{-1/2}+O\left(n^{-3/2}\right)\tag{5}
$$
where $C=\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)=-0.207886224977354566\dots$

---

**Why $\boldsymbol{\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)}$?**

We can rewrite the reasoning given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327831), which uses the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, but use the Binomial Theorem, as above. However, the argument is exactly the same. That is,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-z}-\frac1{1-z}n^{1-z}-\frac12n^{-z}\right]
$$
converges uniformly to an analytic function for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt-1$. For $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt1$, this function is easily seen to be $\zeta(z)$.

By analytic continuation, we get that this function is $\zeta(z)$ for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt-1$. For this question, plug in $z=-\frac12$.

Comment: I've removed the usage of Euler-Maclaurin.

Comment: This doesn't look right. You've lost much the precision in $(1)$ (for example for $k=1$). How do you go from $(4)$ to $(5)$? You can't sum $O(k^{-5/2})$ for $k=1,..,n$ to get $O(n^{-3/2})$. This reasoning would only apply if we needed $\sum_k^N i^{1/2}$ for large $k$ and hence summed $(4)$ from $k$ to $N$

Comment: Where do you think I've lost precision? If $\left|a_k\right|\le Ak^{-5/2}$, then $\left|C-\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_n\right|=\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_n -\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_n\right| \le\frac23An^{-3/2}$.  This even agrees with the Euler-Maclaurin result.

Comment: @A.S.: This means that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^na_n=C+O\left(n^{-3/2}\right)$. Remember that we can compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty a_n$ since $\left|a_n\right|\le An^{-5/2}$.

Comment: @A.S.: note that $(4)$ is in the form $g(k)-g(k-1)=f(k)$. Telescoping the sum says that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nf(k)=g(n)-g(0)$. This gives $(5)$.

Comment: Plug $k=1$ into $(1)$. You'll get $1=1\frac 1{16}+O(1)$. You lost $1/16$th. I just fail to see how you can go from $(4)$ to $(5)$ (I see that its telescoping but the error terms can't be simply added to $O(n^{-3/2})$) and especially how $C$ jumps out...

Comment: @A.S.: I think you're looking at this all wrong.  It is fairly obvious that $(1)$-$(3)$ imply $(4)$. Thus, $$\small\left(\frac23k^{3/2} +\frac12k^{1/2} +\frac1{24}k^{-1/2}\right) -\left(\frac23(k-1)^{3/2} +\frac12(k-1)^{1/2} +\frac1{24}(k-1)^{-1/2}\right) -k^{1/2}$$ is $O\left(k^{-5/2}\right)$.  We can compute the sum from $k=1$ to $\infty$ (that is a well defined constant) and subtract the sum from $k=n+1$ to $\infty$ which we know is $O\left(n^{-3/2}\right)$.

Comment: I have to go for a while. I can continue this later.

Comment: I see. How does that sum from $1$ to $\infty$ work out to $\zeta(-\frac 1 2)\approx -0.2$? Without knowing that, we just know that $C$ is a constant (possibly a huge one - that's the consequence of what I meant by "loss of precision" in my reverse way of thinking about summing). Is there some intuitive way to think about $\zeta(x)$ for $x\le 1$? To me, the fact that the sum of the errors adds up to small $C$ is equivalent to (symbolically on the left) $\sum_1^\infty i^{1/2}\approx -0.2$ and not some other huge number.

Comment: OK, I see how $\zeta(-\frac 1 2)$ pops out but to me it's simply symbolic manipulations as I don't grok the meaning analytical extension as a definition of $\zeta$. How would you compute $\zeta(-\frac 1 2)$?

Comment: @A.S.: I can rewrite the reasoning that I gave in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327831/13854), which uses the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, using the Binomial Theorem, as I did above. However, the argument is exactly the same. That is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{k=1}^nk^{-z} -\frac1{1-z}n^{1-z}-\frac12n^{-z}\right]$$ converges uniformly to an analytic function for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt-1$. For $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt1$, this function is easily seen to be $\zeta(z)$.

Comment: By analytic continuation, we get that this function is $\zeta(z)$ for $\mathrm{Re}(z)\gt-1$. For this question, plug in $z=-\frac12$.

Comment: How would you compute/estimate $\zeta(-\frac 1 2)$?

Comment: @A.S.: There are many ways to compute $\zeta(z)$. However, the way that seems most applicable to this question is to extend the approximation above to $$\begin{align}\small\sum_{k=1}^nk^{1/2} &=\tfrac23n^{3/2} +\tfrac12n^{1/2} +\zeta\left(-\tfrac12\right) +\tfrac1{24}n^{-1/2} -\tfrac1{1920}n^{-5/2} +\tfrac1{9216}n^{-9/2} -\tfrac{11}{163840}n^{-13/2}\\ &\small+\tfrac{65}{786432}n^{-17/2} -\tfrac{223193}{1321205760}n^{-21/2} +\tfrac{52003}{100663296}n^{-25/2} -\tfrac{4741887}{2147483648}n^{-29/2} +O\left(n^{-33/2}\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Plug in $n=10$ to get $18$ places: $$\zeta\left(-\tfrac12\right)=-0.207886224977354566$$

Comment: What is a different way to do it? In this question we are trying to approximate $\sum k^{1/2}$, so we should not compute the sum itself to estimate $\zeta(-\frac 1 2)$.

Comment: We are only computing $\sqrt1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\dots+\sqrt{10}$ to get $\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$ to $18$ places. With that, we can compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}$ very accurately for large $n$. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @A.S.: I see you've edited your comment to ask for a different way to compute $\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)$. We can use the [functional equation for the Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) to get $$\zeta\left(-\frac12\right)=-\frac1{4\pi}\zeta\left(\frac32\right)$$ and we can compute $\zeta\left(\frac32\right)$ using the standard series: $$
\zeta\left(\frac32\right) =\frac1{1^{3/2}}+\frac1{2^{3/2}}+\frac1{3^{3/2}}+\frac1{4^{3/2}}+\dots $$ However, this will take a lot more work to get $18$ places.