# Correct method of integration involving two exponential terms

Tags: integration, exponential-function, infinity

I have an Integrand involving two exponential terms:

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\exp(x^2)}{(1+\exp(x^2))^2} dx
$$

I would like to know what is the best way to integrate such a function without blowing it up?

What if $x^2$ is replaced by two variables $(x^2 + y^2)$ and we have a double integral?
 Will the method of integration remain the same?

I use python and matlab for calculations.

Thanks

Notation fixed.

Comment: i think there is no formula in the known elementary functions

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what can be the best way for numerical integration?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: if $\zeta$ is considered an elementary function, you are wrong.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, isn't $\zeta$ not an elementary function because it's an infinite sum?

Comment: @tilper: also $\sin(x)$ is an infinite sum, namely $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, sine is also a trig function which is an elementary function by definition of elementary functions.  No definition of elementary functions I've seen would include $\zeta$.  Is there such a definition somewhere, or is there a way of defining $\zeta$ that would satisfy the definition of elementary function?

Comment: There is no universal definition of *elementary function*. Those usually involves polynomials, exponentials, logarithms, direct and inverse trigonometric function, $n$-th roots, sums, differences, products, ratios and compositions of them, but we are free to re-define such a class for our purposes.

Comment: The value is a number, not a function.  All constants are "elementary" in the technical sense.  It is true that $\zeta$ is not an elementary function, but so what?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, I wasn't aware that "elementary function" is not a universally defined thing.  I've seen it defined many places and the definition has always been the same, and it always put a "finite" restriction on the $+, -, \times, \div$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You integral can be written as 
$$I=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\cosh^2\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}\,dx=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}\cosh^2(z)}=\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\tanh(z)}{z^{3/2}}\,dz $$
and due to the identity
$$ \tanh(z) = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8z}{(2n+1)^2 \pi^2+ 4z^2} $$
that follows from considering the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass product for the $\cosh$ function, we have:
$$ I = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z}\left[(2n+1)^2 \pi^2+ 4z^2\right]}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^{3/2}}$$
hence:
$$ \boxed{I = \color{red}{\frac{2\sqrt{2}-1}{8\sqrt{\pi}}\,\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)}\approx 0.336859119428877} $$

For the two-variables integral you may ust switch to polar coordinates and apply the same technique, leading to a value of $\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{8}}$.

Comment: nice Jack, i tried ipb and somehow everything became divergent...^^ (+1)

Comment: @tired: I tried that too, but soon after realized that the series expansion for $\tanh$ had to lead to some series solution. The only wonder is that such a series is a value of the $\eta$ function :D

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for the solution.  It does give me some insight in the integral. Is cosh the best way to go about solving such an integral numerically?

Comment: @user3840530: you may use your favourite acceleration method to compute $$\zeta\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}\approx 2.612375 $$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\left(1 + a\mathrm{e}^{x^{2}}\right)^{-1}
&= \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a\mathrm{exp}(x^{2})}} \\
&= \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \left( \frac{1}{a}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}}\right)^{n} \\
&= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{1}{a^{n+1}} \mathrm{e}^{-(n+1)x^{2}} \\
\end{align}

Now integrate the exponential function
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-(n+1)x^{2}} \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}
\end{equation}

Now we have
\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 + a\mathrm{e}^{x^{2}}\right)^{-1} \mathrm{d}x =
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^{1/2}} \frac{1}{a^{n}}
\end{equation}

Taking the derivative of both sides with respect to $a$:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{x^{2}} \left(1 + a\mathrm{e}^{x^{2}}\right)^{-2} \mathrm{d}x =
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^{-1/2}} \frac{1}{a^{n+1}}
\end{equation}

Taking $\lim_{a \to 1}$
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{x^{2}} \left(1 + \mathrm{e}^{x^{2}}\right)^{-2} \mathrm{d}x &=
\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n^{-1/2}} \\
&= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \eta(-1/2) \\
&\approx 0.336859119
\end{align}

$\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function).

Addendum: Response to robjohn's comment.

From the reference I provided for the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function):

"The following relation holds:
    $$\eta(s) = (1 − 2^{1 − s})\zeta(s)$$

While the Dirichlet series expansion for the eta function is convergent only for any complex number $s$ with real part > 0, it is [Abel summable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series) for any complex number. This serves to define the eta function as an [entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)."

Comment: You get the correct answer; however, the last series you give does not converge (the terms do not go to $0$). One can use analytic continuation to extend $\eta(s)$ for $s\le0$, but at least some hand-waving needs to done first.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{x^2}}{\left(1+e^{x^2}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\left(1+e^{-x^2}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Consider
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2}x^{\alpha-1}\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\int_0^\infty\left(e^{-x}-2e^{-2x}+3e^{-3x}-\dots\right)x^{\alpha-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}\\
&=\Gamma(\alpha)\left(1-2^{1-\alpha}+3^{1-\alpha}-\dots\right)\tag{4}\\[6pt]
&=\Gamma(\alpha)\zeta(\alpha-1)\left(1-2^{2-\alpha}\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
The integral in $(2)$ is analytic for $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)\gt0$. For $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)\gt1$ the sum in $(4)$ converges and takes the value in $(5)$. Since the functions in $(2)$ and $(5)$ are analytic and equal for $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)\gt1$, they must be equal for $\mathrm{Re}(\alpha)\gt0$.

Therefore, with $\alpha=\frac12$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{x^2}}{\left(1+e^{x^2}\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\zeta\left(-\tfrac12\right)\left(1-\sqrt8\right)\\
&\doteq0.336859119428876991346\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$

---

**A note on computing $\boldsymbol{\zeta\!\left(-\frac12\right)}$**

We can't use the standard series
$$
\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\tag{7}
$$
to compute $\zeta\!\left(-\tfrac12\right)$ because the series in $(7)$ only converges for $s\gt1$.

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1327831), analytic continuation is used to show that 
$$
\zeta\!\left(-\tfrac12\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\sqrt{k}\,-\tfrac23n^{3/2}-\tfrac12n^{1/2}\right)\tag{8}
$$
The convergence of $(8)$ is very slow; the error is approximately $\frac1{24\sqrt{n}}$. However, by using $8$ terms from the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula, the error is reduced to $\frac{52003}{100663296}n^{-25/2}$.

Thus, using $n=1000$, we get
$$
\zeta\!\left(-\tfrac12\right)=-0.2078862249773545660173067253970493022262\dots\tag{9}
$$