# Integral $\int_0^\infty\Big[\log\left(1+x^2\right)-\psi\left(1+x^2\right)\Big]dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, conjectures, polygamma

I found this intriguing integral:
$$\int_0^\infty\Big[\log\left(1+x^2\right)-\psi\left(1+x^2\right)\Big]dx\approx0.84767315533332877726581...$$
where $\psi(z)=\partial_z\log\Gamma(z)$ is the [digamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).
A lookup in [ISC+](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/) (in "advanced" mode) returned a possible closed form $\frac\pi2\Big[\zeta\!\left(\frac12\right)+2\Big]$ that seems to agree with the numeric value of the integral when calculated to a higher precision. Any ideas how to prove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done by a kind of residue calculation. First of all by parity the integral is $\frac12 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$. Considering this as a contour integral in the $x$-plane, we would like to pull the contour to $i\infty$. There will be two obstacles:

- an infinite number of poles of $\psi(x)$ given by $x_n=i\sqrt n$ with $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ Note that 
  $$\operatorname{res}_{x=x_n}\psi\left(1+x^2\right)=\color{blue}{\frac{i}{2\sqrt n}}$$
- a logarithmic branch cut $(i,i\infty)$ of the function $\ln(1+x^2)$. Note that on this branch cut the logarithm jumps by $\color{red}{2\pi i}$.

So we deform the contour to the following: a horizontal ray $r_L=(-\infty+i\sqrt N,-0+i\sqrt N)$, a contour $C$ going counterclockwise around the logarithmic branch cut from $-0+i\sqrt N$ to $-0+i\sqrt N$, and another horizontal ray $r_R=(+0+i\sqrt N,\infty+i\sqrt N)$. Now we have 
$$\int_C= \color{red}{2\pi i} \cdot i \left(\sqrt N-1\right)-2\pi i\sum_{1\leq n<N}
\color{blue}{\frac i{2\sqrt n}}=\pi\left[2+\sum_{1\leq n<N}\frac1{\sqrt n}-2\sqrt{N}\right].$$
Using the known asymptotic behavior $\psi(z\to\infty)=\ln z+\frac1{2z}+O\left(z^{-2}\right)$, we can show that integrals over the rays $r_L$ and $r_R$ vanish in the limit $N\to\infty$.

Therefore the integral we are interested in is equal to
$$\mathcal I=\frac12\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_C=\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\sum_{1\leq n<N}\frac1{\sqrt n}-2\sqrt{N}\right].$$
Finally, that the remaining limit is equal to $\zeta\left(\frac12\right)$ can be shown relatively easily: see, for instance, [this approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1485833/73025).

Comment: I tried yesterday to simplify your approach by instead considering the function $ \log(z+i) - \psi(1+z^{2})$. But the integral doesn't vanish on the sides of a rectangle in the upper half-plane. Also, isn't $\lim_{N \to \infty} \left( \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^{s}}  - \frac{N^{1-s}}{1-s} \right)$ a representation of the Riemann zeta function in the critical strip?

Comment: @RandomVariable The logarithm contributes only as a constant jump, so it seems difficult to further simplify - though maybe I misunderstand your point. Also, for vanishing of the ray integrals it is important to have both logarithms. Your second remark is absolutely true.

Comment: Actually, you would need to consider $f(z)= {\color{red}{2}}\log(z+i) - \psi(1+z^{2}).$ But $f(z)$ decays on the order of $\frac{1}{z}$ when $|z|$ is large in magnitude, while $\log(1+z^{2}) - \psi(1+z^{2})$ decays on the order of $\frac{1}{z^{2}}$. So, as you mentioned, the ray integrals don't vanish as $N \to \infty$.

Answer (score 8):

Choi and Srivastava list a rather obscure, but useful, series:

$$\psi(x)-\log(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)-\frac{1}{x+k}\right)\tag{1}$$

Let $x\to x^{2}+1$, then we have:

$$\log(x^{2}+1)-\psi(x^{2}+1)=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)-\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)$$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\log(x^{2}+1)-\psi(x^{2}+1)\right)dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)-\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)$$

Assuming one may can switch integral and sum:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\log(x^{2}+1)-\psi(x^{2}+1)\right)dx=-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)-\frac{1}{x^{2}+k+1}\right)$$

$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2\sqrt{k+1}\sqrt{k+2}-(2k+3)}{\sqrt{k+1}}\tag{2}$$

I admit I did not evaluate it manually (**EDIT**: I added some stuff below), but tech showed that the sum converges to $$-\zeta(1/2)-2$$

Thus, we finally have:

$$\frac{-\pi}{2}\left(-\zeta(1/2)-2\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}\zeta(1/2)+\pi$$

and

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\log(x^{2}+1)-\psi(x^{2}+1)\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{2}\zeta(1/2)+\pi$$

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**more on (1)**:

Begin with the Gamma identity:
$$\Gamma(1+x)=\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{x}\prod_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)^{x+k}}{\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}}$$

log both sides of (1):

$$\log\Gamma(x+1)=x\log(x)-x+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[(x+k)\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)-k\log\left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)\right]$$

diff both sides:

$$\psi(x+1)=\log(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)-\frac{1}{x+k+1}\right]$$

Thus, $$\psi(x)=\log(x)+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left[\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x+k}\right)-\frac{1}{x+k}\right]$$

also, note $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left[\psi(x)-\log(x)\right]=0$

**more on (2)**:

Partial N sums in terms of Zeta.

$$\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{N}\left(2\sqrt{k+2}-\frac{2k}{\sqrt{k+1}}-\frac{3}{\sqrt{k+1}}\right)\tag{3}$$

$$2\sum_{k=0}^{N}\sqrt{k+2}=-2\zeta\left(-1/2, N+3\right)+2\zeta(-1/2)-2\tag{4}$$

$$2\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{k}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\left[2\zeta(-1/2,N+2)+2\zeta(1/2,N+2)-2\zeta(1/2)+2\zeta(-1/2)\right]\tag{5}$$

$$3\sum_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=3\zeta(1/2)-3\zeta(1/2,N+2)\tag{6}$$

Put together (4), (5), (6) in accordance with (3). $\zeta(s,n)=\zeta(s)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^{s}}$:

$$\begin{align}-2\zeta\left(-1/2, N+3\right)+2\zeta(-1/2)-2-\left[2\zeta(-1/2,N+2)+2\zeta(1/2,N+2)\\ -2\zeta(1/2)+2\zeta(-1/2)\right]-\left[3\zeta(1/2)-3\zeta(1/2,N+2)\right]\end{align}$$

$$=2\zeta(-1/2,N+2)-2\zeta(-1/2,N+3)+\zeta(1/2,N+2)-\zeta(1/2)-2\tag{7}$$

But, $ \;\ \;\ \;\ \begin{align}2\zeta(-1/2,N+2)-2\zeta(-1/2,N+3)=2\sqrt{N+2}\end{align}\\$

thus, (7) becomes:

$$2\sqrt{N+2}+\zeta(1/2,N+2)-\zeta(1/2)-2$$

and $$\lim_{N\to \infty}\left[2\sqrt{N+2}+\zeta(1/2,N+2)\right]=0$$

so all that remains is $$\boxed{-\zeta(1/2)-2}$$

Answer (score 5):

There is also a quick derivation available by utilizing Binet's first integral for the digamma function
$$ \psi(z) =\log z -\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) e^{-zt} \, dt, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{Re}(z)>0 $$
and the integral
$$ \zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) t^{s-1} e^{-t} \, dt, \hspace{0.5cm} \text{Re}(s)>0 $$
where setting $s=\frac{1}{2}$ gives
$$ \sqrt{\pi} \left(\zeta \left(\tfrac{1}{2} \right)+2 \right) = \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt $$

Letting $z=1+x^2$ and applying the Fubini theorem gives
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \left(\psi(1+x^2)-\log(1+x^2) \right) dx = -\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) e^{-(1+x^2)t} \, dt \, dx $$
$$ = - \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) e^{-t} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-tx^2} \, dx \, dt = - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^t-1}+1-\frac{1}{t} \right) \frac{e^{-t}}{\sqrt{t}} , dt = -\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\zeta \left(\tfrac{1}{2} \right)+2 \right) $$

This method admits considerable generalization. For example, we can use it to show that
$$ \int_0^{\infty} x^{r-1} \left(\psi(1+x^s)-\log(1+x^s) \right) \, dx = - \frac{\pi}{s \sin \left(\frac{\pi r}{s} \right)} \left(\zeta \left(1-\tfrac{r}{s} \right) + \frac{s}{r} \right), \hspace{0.5cm} 0<r<s. $$

Comment: Awesome answer.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement Dave's awesome answer, I'm adding a proof of the integral $$\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}+1-\frac{1}{x} \right) x^{s-1} e^{-x} \, \mathrm dx \ , \quad \Re (s)>0. $$

All we need are the well-known integrals $$\Gamma(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-x} \, \mathrm dx \ ,  \quad \Re(s)>0 \tag{1} $$ and $$\Gamma(s) \zeta(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} \, \mathrm dx \ , \quad \Re(s)>1. \tag{2}$$

Subtracting $(1)$ from $(2)$, we get $$ \Gamma(s) \zeta(s) - \Gamma(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \left(\frac{1}{e^{x}-1} - e^{-x} \right) \, \mathrm dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}{e^{x}-1} \, \mathrm dx \ , \quad \Re(s)>1.$$

The integral on the right side of the equation can be rewritten as
$$ \begin{align} \ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}e^{-x}}{e^{x}-1} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}  \right) x^{s-1} e^{-x} \,  \mathrm dx+ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-2} e^{-x} \, \mathrm dx  \\ &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x} \right) x^{s-1} e^{-x} \,  \mathrm dx + \Gamma(s-1)  , \end{align} $$  where $\frac{1}{x}$ is the first term of the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{e^x-1}$ at the origin.

Dividing both sides of the equation by $\Gamma(s)$, we get $$\zeta(s) - 1  = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}  \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{e^x-1}- \frac{1}{x}\right) x^{s-1} e^{-x} \, \mathrm dx + \frac{1}{s-1} , \quad \Re(s) >0. \tag{3}$$

To get the integral in the form given in Dave's answer, add $1$ to both sides of the equation and use the fact that $$1 = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}e^{-x} \, \mathrm dx.$$